# "Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset" in Jenkins, from execute shell command

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I have a Jenkins job and it seems to have perforce set up correctly. However, when I tried to use p4 command in the execute shell of jenkins, got an error "Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset". Following is the execute shell and log, what should I do to make it work?

Execute shell:
p4 -P %P4TICKET% edit ...

Log:

[JobName] $ /usr/bin/p4 login -a -p

...

- p4 -P %P4TICKET% edit ...

Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.

Answer (score 1):

Try ${P4TICKET} instead of %P4TICKET%. "%VARIABLE%" is strictly a Windows convention, and doesn't work in unix for referencing variables.